# How to start mongod from boot script without running as root?

Tags: linux, mongodb

mongod runs fine as my own system user, but when I attempt to start it from a boot script using sudo, it fails.

I'm not running it as root, i'm doing:

```
sudo -u normaluser /user/local/bin/mongod --fork --logpath=/var/log/mongodb.log --logappend >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The log file is writeable by normaluser and I have no problem running it as normaluser directly.

How can I start this on boot?

Comment: What distribution are you running?

Comment: Also what is the error you are getting? What is the outcome of running that command in your shell?

Comment: Seems fine from shell. It just fails on boot.

Comment: Did you install it with a package manager like yum?

Comment: Also, if you could, please elaborate on where you are actually placing the command and how you are trying to get it to start.

Comment: Placed in /etc/rc.local along with other server starts, which are fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, given our conversation in the comments above I think you should look at the following file:

[Red Hat based init script](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/init.d-mongod)

It seems like you might want to follow that and write something like:

```
daemon --user normaluser mongod --fork --logpath=/var/log/mongodb.log --logappend >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thanks. No `daemon` programme though. I'll look into it!

Comment: Did you try as root? I'm pretty sure it should exist as root user, but please don't use sudo in the actual script.

Comment: I would look at other init scripts for centos 5.5 and see how they do it, but from what I can tell they are using daemon.